# How to read such input in Java?

Tags: java, input, inputstream, user-input

I have an input:

```
aN b c
a1 a2 a3 ... aN
```

for example:

```
4 3 2
2 1 2 1 (I have here 'a' numbers, a = 4)
5 6 3
3 9 5 7 3 (I have here 'a' numbers, a = 5)
0 0 0
```

I want to stop reading an input when a or b or c will equal 0. I tried this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
        String line = "";
        int a = -1, b = -1, c = -1;
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

        while (a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0) 
        {
            line = in.readLine();
            String tmp[] = line.split(" ");
            a = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
            c = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);
            System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", c = " + c);
            line = in.readLine();
            list.clear();
            tmp = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                list.add(new Integer(Integer.valueOf(tmp[i])));
            }
            System.out.println("List = 4 3 2" + list);   
        }   
    }        
}
```

but with this simple input:

```
4 3 2
2 1 2 1
5 6 3
3 9 5 7 3
0 0 0
```

even if I type 3 zeros, my program still waits for an input. How to improve it?

**EDIT:**

**Guy you misunderstood. I NEED to have a second readline cause I need to read a second (fourth, sixth) line of input ...**

Comment: What does the println() call say for the lines with zeroes?

Comment: remove the second: line = in.readLine(); the while loop should process one line at a time

Comment: @dutt: when `a` or `b` or `c` is equal 0, it should break a while loop

Comment: @opi: nope, doesnt work too :/ Maybe I should do it entirely different?

Comment: Seems like class/home work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (true) 
{
        line = in.readLine();
        String tmp[] = line.split(" ");
        a = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
        c = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);
        if (a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", c = " + c);
        line = in.readLine();
        list.clear();
        tmp = line.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(Integer.valueOf(tmp[i])));
        }
        System.out.println("List = 4 3 2" + list);   
    }
```

Comment: tried break, doesnt work, gives: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527) at Test.main(Test.java:26) Java Result: 1`

Comment: try { a = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]); .... c = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {a = 0;}

Comment: hm, worked when I ran this for the second time, thanks!:)

Comment: Please don't give potted answers to homework coding questions.  The OP won't learn anything by copying-and-pasting your code.

Comment: ok, Stephen, i agree, but she know the break statement now. im new here, and im learning the rules, thanks :)

Comment: I knew a `break` statement earlier but thanks anyway:P

Comment: I know that you already knew. :)

Answer (score 3):

After your program reads a line with 0's, it's still waiting for another line before it will stop..

The easiest fix (maybe not the cleanest):

```
while (true)
{
   line = in.readLine();
   String tmp[] = line.split(" ");
   a = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
   b = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
   c = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);
   if (a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0)
     break;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Please don't give potted answers to homework coding questions. The OP won't learn anything by copying-and-pasting your code.

Comment: @StephenC I gave a sentence to briefly explain the problem, then changed 1 line of OP's code and inserted 2, that doesn't feel like a 'potted answer' to me. If OP wants to learn and doesn't understand, she's free to ask for clarification.

Comment: OK ... I was a bit hasty in your case ... downvote reversed.

Answer (score 3):

You have two lines of:

```
line = in.readLine();
```

So when reading 3 zeroes at the first `readLine()`, you still wait for the other one.
You can change the order, or use `break` after first readline, if at least one of a,b,c is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to answer a question in a way that will help the OP to learn.

1) Identify the problem.

> "The problem is that your program as written only tests to see whether it needs to stop after reading an even number of lines.  You can see this by looking at *where* you are reading the input."

2) Give hints as to how to solve the immediate problem.

> "If you want to be able to stop on an odd number of lines, you will need another test ... after reading an odd-numbered line".

3) Point out other problems.

> "In fact, you probably should also check that:
>
> - the result of the `readLine()` calls are not `null` (this happens when your program reaches the end of input; e.g. if you type ^D on Linux or ^Z on Windows),
> - there are at least 3 numbers on the first line, third line, fifth line and so on,
> - and a few other things.
>
> If you don't test these, your program will die with an exception when given bad input."

---

It is actually harder / more work to answer a question this way (for an experienced programmer).  But it is really important to encourage a beginner to start *thinking* in code.  After all, that is the *real* goal of their homework.  (Not getting the marks, not producing the perfect solution ...)

Comment: Under other circumstances, I would have elaborated a bit more in my answer, but I think the time for that has probably passed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class MultipleInputs {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
        while(true){
            String line = in.readLine();
            List<Integer> numbers = getNumbers(line);
            if(numbers.get(0) != 0 && numbers.get(1) != 0 && numbers.get(2) != 0){
                String line2 = in.readLine();
                List<Integer> numbers2 = getNumbers(line2);
                //TODO: do something with numbers2 
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private static List<Integer> getNumbers(String line){
        String [] strs = line.split(" ");
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(String str : strs){
            try{
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
            }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Do nothing, just ignore the sub-string 
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't give potted answers to homework coding questions. The OP won't learn anything by copying-and-pasting your code.

Comment: @StephenC If someone wants to learn, he/she can learn from code too. IF I post a question, I would be very happy if someone answers by showing me a completely different approach to my question !
Its always better to show alternate solution to a problem.

Comment: See my Answer for an example of how to help the OP without providing a potted solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
while((line=in.readLine()) != null){
        String tmp[] = line.split(" ");
        a = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
        c = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);
        if (a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0) {
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(Integer.valueOf(tmp[i])));
        }
}
```

Comment: Please don't give potted answers to homework coding questions. The OP won't learn anything by copying-and-pasting your code.

Comment: @StephenC - If someone wants to learn, I would very much be willing to provide them with code. Everybody has their own views and takes on how a problem can be solved. Nevertheless, all I did was improve upon the existing code by making the FOR a bit more robust. That doesn't seem to be **"potted"** at all.

Comment: See my Answer for an example of how to help a student.  You need to help them understand their mistake and how to solve it.  In particular, you need to help them to THINK algorithmically.